# Can resetting initial/Start Auto-Increment value affect speed of queries?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a 6 million record table with an auto-increment ID PK.  Due to various operations over the last several weeks, my starting ID is 2 million. Updates and other queries take a long time, and I'm wondering if having an iD range from 2mil to 8mil vs starting at 1 to 6 million could be responsible? I've noticed anecdotally that if I do selects/updates using a range of say `ID>1000000 and ID<1001000` seems to be slower than `ID>1 and ID<1000`.

Is it worth it to remove the existing PK and add a new one starting at 1? I know I can do

`ALTER TABLE tablename Auto-Increment=1`

but I cannot do this here with 6 million existing records and Auto-Increment IDs already.

Clearly I can do try and test but for various reasons including the time it is going to take given the size of table, indexes, etc I'd prefer to ask before going to the time and effort if anyone knows the answer definitively.

**Update:**
For now I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table_new LIKE table;
```

To dupe the table with indexes and all

Then:

`Alter Table table_new set Auto-Increment=1`

So the empty duped table re-sets count to 1

Then I inserted from the original table to the duped table:

`Insert into Table_New (FieldA,FieldB,FieldC)
Select FieldA,FIeldB,FieldC from Table`

To insert all the records minus the ID field so that the Auto-Increment is added per inserted record, starting at 1 as the re-set specified and finally of course:

```
 RENAME TABLE table TO table_old;
 RENAME TABLE table_new TO table;
```

Comment: I highly doubt the PK is the source of any slowness you see.  What other keys or indexes do you have on the table

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Well definitely too many, looking into removing as many as I can as well. But I have noticed that the higher the ID range seems to affect speed so trying to do this as another potentially beneficial step. In addition to the fact that having the records start with 2,552,125 just can't lead to anything good. Added my interim solution to my original Q above.

Comment: you should start by rebuilding all the indexes on the table.  If you've done a lot of manipulation of the data, its likely there's some fragmentation there.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Is that as "simple" as dropping and recreating each index?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way in Mysql to do it, but that would work (you will see a bit of a performance hit while it rebuilds the indexes).  You can also do an empty alter table statement to force a defragmentation of the indexes.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html

Comment: @MarshallTigerus For what it is worth, after re-setting AI to 1, removing  few indexes (not recreating any) and reducing a few field lenghts (e.g VarChar from 255 to 50 where warranted) the update that was failing to every update took 3 minutes. I am going to drop and reindex the index that is specifically used for this update and report back if that helped.